# (About Radix Sort) I'm in trouble understanding the code from my professor

Tags: python

I cannot understand what this line means:

```
queue = [list() for _ in range(k)]
```

This is the full code:

```
for i in range(1, maxlen+1):     
    queue = [list() for _ in range(k)]   
    for word in words:

        word += (maxlen - len(word)) * ' '

        if ord(word[-i]) >= 97:
            queue[ord(word[-i]) - (97)].append(word)
        else:
            queue[0].append(word)


    words = sum(queue, [])

for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].replace(" ", "")

print(words)
```

Comment: this part create the list of the lists

Comment: This is not the full code because we don’t know what are `k`, `maxlen`, `words`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
queue = [list() for _ in range(k)]
```

it is creating a list of empty lists which is called queue. Queue is a list containing k empty lists

Answer (score 1):

That simply just creates a list the number of the variable `k` times of a empty list, so see example:

```
a=3
print([list() for i in range(a)])
```

Output:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

_ is simply a variable such as i or j. You are using an underscore to show that it is a throwaway varaible which you do not use again.

See also [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is python’s list comprehension, which is shortened code for

```
queue = []
for _ in range(k):
    queue.append(list())
```

underscore _ is a python variable meant to represent the last accessed variable and typically is used as a throwaway variable that the script code does not wish to reference